# Disabling test classes by using @Disabled annotation not taking effect

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

In a spring boot project I wanted to disable all testcases as in any case most of them were failing because of environment and code changes. I wanted to disable all of them at first by applying @Disabled annotation at class level and then removing that annotation one test class at a time to fix them. However that strategy did not work as some test cases still kept failing & some others were giving errors & I was forced to fix them. Buy if a test class is annotated with @Disabled, test cases inside it are not supposed to be executed. Will @Disabled at class level, prevent not only methods annotated with @Test to execute, but also methods annotated with @Before, @After, @BeforeAll, @AfterAll as well? Or they will keep executing & may lead to test case getting executed?

**Update**

A Test class on which @Disabled annotation worked:

```
package com.mycompany.xxx.service.game.db.service;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import com.mycompany.xxx.service.game.domain.db.ITablePlayerDataService;
import com.mycompany.xxx.service.game.domain.dto.TablePlayerView;
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.config.location=classpath:application-integ.yml,"
                + "${user.home}/newworkspace/common-config.yml" })
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@DisplayName("TablePlayerDataServiceImpl - Test Cases")
@Ignore
class TablePlayerDataServiceImplTest {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TablePlayerDataServiceImplTest.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private ITablePlayerDataService tablePlayerDataService;

    @Test
    void testGetPlayersInThisTournamentAndRound() {
        List<TablePlayerView> tablePlayerViews = 
                tablePlayerDataService.getPlayersInThisTournamentAndRound(58L, (byte)1);
        
        tablePlayerViews.forEach(e -> logger.info(e.toString()));
        assertEquals(2, tablePlayerViews.size());
    }

}
```

After I run "mvn clean install", I get following result:

```
Tests run: 113, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 27
```

My expectation was, it should say skipped: 113 because I have annotated with @Disabled all 45 test classes.

Comment: When applied at the class-level, all test methods and lifecycle callbacks inside should be disabled. "@Disabled is used to signal that the annotated test class or test method is currently disabled and should not be executed." - https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Disabled.html. Without further info, it's hard to say why the "..strategy did not work..".

Answer (score -1):

Use @Ignore annotation for the class if the version is JUnit4, @Disabled if it's JUnit5.

Comment: I tried @Ignore on a test class. No effect. Being executed as usual.

Comment: Can you post more details on test class about the annotations being used and class it is extending with package etc.

Comment: Update the question with details.